# Conditional Expectation on a Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Say we have $X$~Poisson($\lambda_1$), $Y$~Poisson($\lambda_2$) and $S=X+Y$.

We therefore know $S$~$Poisson(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$.

I understand how to calculate E(X|S=s) when S is realised to a discrete value. How would we calculate E(X|S) if S remains a random variable?

I know that the result must be a function of S, but following what we would do if S=s:

E(X|S) = $\sum xP(X=x|S)=\sum x\frac{P(X=x,S)}{P(S)}$

the notation P(S) doesn't make sense. How does one calculate this?

Comment: Just replace $s$ by $S$ in the expression you get for $EX|S=s)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb E [X \vert S]$ is a random variable. There are many definitions of this that you can find, but they typically require background in measure-theoretic probability in order to deal with cases more general than the one you present.

Here is a simple definition that works here. First, define the function

$$ g(s) = \mathbb E [X \vert S=s].$$

Then we *define* $\mathbb E [X\vert S] = g(S)$. That is, $E[X\vert S]$ is the function $g$ evaluated at the realisation of the random variable $S$.

Notice that this is different from the expectation of $X$ conditional on the event $\{S=S\}$, which would just be equal to the unconditional expectation of $X$.

If you are familiar with more general definitions of conditional expectation, you can verify that the definition I’ve given above is equivalent in the setting you’ve described.